# Autocomplete user webpage

Tags: wordpress, comments, field

i would like to autoasign every user that comments a custom webpage ex: http://example.com and make every username clickable.

I want it to be automatically, so they cannot complete the website field

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the "website" field on the comment form and give it a default value instead? (Use `@Jan` when you reply in a comment and I get a notification)